# Randomly generating binomial values of 1 and 2 using rbinom in R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a random number using `rbinom()` with a binomial distribution. However, instead of generating a 0 or 1, I would like to replace the 0 with a value of 2. I have tried `rbinom(n=1, size = 1, prob = 0.75) + 1`, and then changing values of 2 into values of 1 and vice versa in a data frame, but I'm struggling to work out a solution that doesn't involve having to do that. I thought about using `sample.int()` in a similar manner but also struggled with this.

I would like to understand whether I could replace the 0 in a binomial distribution from `rbinom` with a value of 2, so that it draws from a 2 or a 1 instead of 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on your actual question?

Comment: I am trying to understand if there is a way to change the value 0 generated by rbinom to a value of 2 within the rbinom framework.

Comment: `sample.int(2, 1, prob=c(0.25, 0.75))`

Comment: @user20650 Thank you, if you put this as an answer I will mark it answered.

Comment: Why not just set `prob= 0.25` and then add 1 to the outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sample from a vector `x = c(1,2)` with probabilites `c(0.25, 0.75)` you can use

```
sample.int(2, 1, prob=c(0.25, 0.75))
```

or

```
s = rbinom(1, 1, prob = 0.25) # sample zeros or ones
# and convert zeros to two
2 - s
```

Check that it gives the expected results by drawing more samples

```
set.seed(76422247)
s = sample.int(2, 1e6, TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.75))
proportions(table(s))
#        1        2 
# 0.250207 0.749793 

set.seed(76422247)
s2 = 2 - rbinom(1e6, 1, prob = 0.25)
proportions(table(s2))
#        1        2 
# 0.250207 0.749793
```